# Printing several \t in one line

Tags: c, printf

For some weird reason my little program over here doesn't show up the way I want to.The last `\t` before Quit for a weird reason doesn't do anything.

Can anyone explain me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n,litera;
void main (void)
{   n=1;
     printf("File\tEdit\tView\tCompile\tQuit\n");
     printf("Selectati optiunea aleasa:");
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)`, BTW.

Comment: Well I was expecting it to appear like :

Comment: File     Edit     View     Compile    Quit with 5 spaces between them

Comment: That did the job!Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3121023; I'd put the `\n` into he format-string.

Comment: Why any TABs at all? Wouldn't a single `" "`  just do it?

Comment: A tab and "5 spaces" are totally different things. A tab, btw, is a single char that is interpreted by different programs in different ways. The code editors usually interpret it as "jump to the next column that is a multiple of N" where "N" is 2, 4 or 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing really weird about it. Since `Compile` is more than 4 letters long, it eats up three spaces into the next tab block. Hence the result. Use two `\t\t` otherwise.

Here's a Q&D solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #define TAB "    "

 int n,litera;

 int main (void)
 {   n=1;
     printf("File"TAB"Edit"TAB"View"TAB"Compile"TAB"Quit\n");
     printf("Selectati optiunea aleasa:");
     return 0;
 }
```